# Compass only running in parts

Tags: ruby, compass-sass

As i am trying to get my version on the command line by typing:

```
compass -version
```

I am receving the following error:

```
Errno::ENOENT on line ["25"] of /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/compass/version.rb: No such file or directory - /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/compass/../../VERSION.yml
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

Apart from that everything is running fine.

Anyone with the same problem, a workaround, a solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a reported and confirmed bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ruby-compass/+bug/1100018